# Allowing mysql to recognize an apostrophe when using the select command

Tags: php, mysql, ios, xml, parsing

I have been using xml to parse. Although I can insert my data fine into a mysql database, I cannot receive whenever there is a apostrophe. I am using

```
stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding : NSUTF8StringEncoding
```

for the insert, which succeeds in placing it in as '. When I try to select however, mysql gets confused and shoots me with no response. Is there a way to replace an apostrophe with something recognizable before sending it up to the database and then parsing it back into the correct format when receiving?

Comment: Are you using PHP on the server?

Comment: I am using php. Sorry I left that out

Answer (score 3):

You need to use [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60496/1415038). You need to parametrize your MySQL queries so you won't be vulnerable to [SQL injection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection).

Example using PDO:

```
$stmt = $pdo->prepare('SELECT * FROM employees WHERE name = :name');

$stmt->execute(array(':name' => $name));

foreach ($stmt as $row) {
    // do something with $row
}
```

Example using mysqli:

```
$stmt = $dbConnection->prepare('SELECT * FROM employees WHERE name = ?');
$stmt->bind_param('s', $name);

$stmt->execute();

$result = $stmt->get_result();
while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
    // do something with $row
}
```